# How to make VLC actually remember what I tell it?

Tags: windows, command-line, vlc-media-player, gui

I keep being forced to select "Always on top" in the "View" menu in VLC. It forgets this setting the moment I close VLC. And then I have to repeat it again and again and again...

I can't find any mention of such a command-line option, so I apparently can't force it to use this setting by launching VLC with a special command either: https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Command_line/

(But even if it did have a command line flag for this, it would probably not respect it anyway. VLC ignores many of the documented flags on that page. For example, anything related to volume and setting the window size.)

But why does it not remember any settings? Who would want the settings you set to be forgotten every time you close the program?

3.0.11.

Comment: Of course, if you set the Video option to start full screen (by definition, *on top*), that *is* retained... but that doesn't answer your question regarding audio or other usage.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Not talking about fullscreen. I don't know where you got that from.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why "Always on top" in VLC is not persistent. This question might be
better raised in the VLC forums.

If you are looking for a solution, you will need third-party software.
You may write your own, using a tool such as
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
or use one of the ready-made software below:

- [Skrommel's WinWarden](https://www.dcmembers.com/skrommel/download/winwarden/)
  Can be programmed to control all aspects of the display of any window,
  but through a rather complex `.ini` file.
- [Skrommel's OnTop](https://www.dcmembers.com/skrommel/download/ontop/)
  makes it simpler to set a window to topmost with just a click on a traybar icon.
- [Eusing Auto Window Manager](http://www.eusing.com/WindowManager/WindowManager.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Try set it in following:

**1.**  Menu: **Tools** -> Preferences // *or* **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>**

[image]

**2.**  [**√**] All *in* **Show settings**

[image]

**3.** Type "top" and click in **Video**

**4.** Mark option "Always on top" and save

**5.** Restart VLC....

[image]